Plastic Rod in Bathtub Drain
I'm a new homeowner of a 7 year old house.  The bathtub has a drain plug that pops up.  I unscrewed it and pulled out 7 years of hair (it seemed like).  But to my surprise, this long orange rod also came out.  It's plastic and the yellow end seems like some sort of velcro.  What is it?  Do I need to put it back in?




It is a drain clean out tool that someone forgot to remove.
The velcro-like end snags hair.
It can be used without removing the drain plug.

that plus the information that there was a lot of hair to remove paints an amusing (or sad) picture - of someone who tries to clean the bathtub, loses the drain clean tool, and then... just gives up on ever trying again.

This is the correct answer: I bought one 2--3x as long black in a European equivalent of a Dollar General 10--15y ago; and have used it multiple times over the years. This one is so short that you risk losing it in there...

@user3445853 It's originally longer but it snapped. There's supposed to be a fitting on the end that locks into a handle.

Only thing this answer is missing is a recommendation to buy another one of those and complete the job that one failed at...

You are all right.  Today I saw the exact same hair removal tool at my local hardware store.  Thank you!
